# How to separate different traces in a python plotly scattergeo line map

Tags: python, geolocation, plotly, line

I'm plotting different routes using plotly scattergeo in python and my issue is that i'm not able to separate the lines between different trips, and all are joined as if they're only one.

[image: There are two trips in this image, Ecuatorial Guiney to Lisbon and Ecuatorial Guiney to Cape Town, but even with two separate trips there's a connecting line from the end of trip 1 (to Lisbon) to the start of trip 2 (to Guiney)]

There are two trips in this image, Ecuatorial Guiney to Lisbon and  Ecuatorial Guiney to Cape Town, but even with two separate trips there's a connecting line from the end of trip 1 (to Lisbon) to the start of trip 2

This is the code I'm using to generate the plot:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go


lat = [1.769395, 3.909938, 4.416706, 4.402889, 4.470340,
       9.905343,14.541283, 38.611303, 1.769395,2.958316,
       -6.161784, -12.832035, -22.959316, -34.089891]
lon = [9.687394, 9.012994, 7.696527, 5.590180, -4.445836,
       -15.484433, -23.936471, -9.516133, 9.687394, 12.089027,
       -4.623525, 12.121931, 10.773240, 17.804489]

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=lon,
        lat=lat,
        marker={'size': 10}))

fig.update_layout(
        margin={'l': 0, 't': 0, 'b': 0, 'r': 0},
        mapbox={
            'center': {'lon': 10, 'lat': 10},
            'style': "stamen-terrain",
            'center': {'lon': -20, 'lat': -20},
            'zoom': 1})
#To be able to see the plot while using pycharm
fig.write_image('C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.png')
fig.show()
```

My aim would be to have different traces separated, not all joined up.

Comment: Hola Ignacio, please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) so it will be easier to help.

Comment: The mcve has been added, thank you for the heads up

Comment: What do you mean with separated?

Comment: That the end of a trace should not be connected to the start of the next one, as seen in the picture where it jumps from Lisbon to Guiney trough Africa.

Comment: Do you mind to create lat_trip1, lon_trip1 and lat_trip2, lon_trip2? As they are mixed the actual behavior it's normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that trip1 ends at index 7 you can split `lon` and `lat` by trip. Here the full code

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

lat = [1.769395, 3.909938, 4.416706, 4.402889, 4.470340,
       9.905343,14.541283, 38.611303, 1.769395,2.958316,
       -6.161784, -12.832035, -22.959316, -34.089891]
lon = [9.687394, 9.012994, 7.696527, 5.590180, -4.445836,
       -15.484433, -23.936471, -9.516133, 9.687394, 12.089027,
       -4.623525, 12.121931, 10.773240, 17.804489]

lon_trip1 = lon[:8]
lat_trip1 = lat[:8]
lon_trip2 = lon[8:]
lat_trip2 = lat[8:]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=lon_trip1,
        lat=lat_trip1,
        name="trip1",
        marker={'size': 10}))
fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        mode="markers+lines",
        lon=lon_trip2,
        lat=lat_trip2,
        name="trip2",
        marker={'size': 10}))

fig.update_layout(
        margin={'l': 0, 't': 0, 'b': 0, 'r': 0},
        mapbox={
            'center': {'lon': 10, 'lat': 10},
            'style': "stamen-terrain",
            'center': {'lon': -20, 'lat': -20},
            'zoom': 1})
#To be able to see the plot while using pycharm
# fig.write_image('C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.png')
fig.show()
```

[image]